# Adding and reading from a Config file

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I have created a `C# console based project`. In that project i have some variables like `companyName`, `companyType` which are Strings.

```
companyName="someCompanyName";
companyType="someCompanyType";
```

I need to create a config file and read values from it, and then initialize the variables `companyName`, `companyType` in the code.

1. How can i create a config file (or equivalent) ?
2. How can i read from the config file ?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10718830/205859) may help

Answer (score 112, accepted):

1. Add an [`Application Configuration File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/index?redirectedfrom=MSDN) item to your project (<kbd>Right -Click</kbd> Project > Add item). This will create a file called `app.config` in your project.
2. Edit the file by adding entries like `<add key="keyname" value="someValue" />` within the `<appSettings>` tag.
3. Add a reference to the `System.Configuration` dll, and reference the items in the config using code like `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyname"]`.

Comment: This no longer works

Answer (score 27):

```
Configuration configManager = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
KeyValueConfigurationCollection confCollection = configManager.AppSettings.Settings;

confCollection["YourKey"].Value = "YourNewKey";


configManager.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configManager.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
```

Comment: Some explanation would help.

Comment: The source code defenitely lacks comment. So it does not provide a solution/answer the question imo.

Comment: simple enough though

Answer (score 14):

1. Right click on the project file -> Add -> New Item -> Application Configuration File. This will add an `app.config` (or `web.config`) file to your project.
2. The [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class would be a good start. You can use it to read different configuration values from the configuration file.

I suggest you start reading the MSDN document about [Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx).