# Connectionstring: is it the right form?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to SQL Database C# projects and I have a problem with connecting to my database in a windows form application which is a single user app and I want to use it just for myself. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 On windows7 64-bit and have SQL Server 2008 and 2012 Installed on my DELL Inspiron15 3521 Laptop.

First, I don't know if my connection string is correct or in a correct form. this is my connection string:

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=Library;Integrated Security=True";
```

Secondly, I have another problem: when this code is running in Visual Studio 2012, it's telling me that `"Cannot open database "Library" requested by the login. The login failed."`. This is happening when my authentication in SQL server is Windows Authentication and I don't have any login information add to the database. Is any configuration for it or it's just my code that is wrong?

Comment: You can try to use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`

Comment: As you are using VS 2012 it should be easy to open "View -> Server Explorer" right click on "Data Connections" -> Add Connection. The following dialog will help you to connect. The connection string can be copied from the newly created connection via "Properties" (if you need it)

Comment: Have you tried setting `Data Source =` to your SQL Server 2008 server name like for example `Demo-My-DSK024\SQLEXPRESS` or something which can be found by right clicking server name and on the generals tab?

Comment: See also: [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: No I did not, As I have said i'm new to this, please tell me how i can do it?

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string should be like this:

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="ConnStringDb1" 
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Library;Integrated Security=True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: thank you for answering but my connection string is used for a windows for application and from where i know the C# code's your code is in XAML language and it's can be used in WPF if i am right. So Please make it in C# and i will apply it to my project and hope it works. thank you

Comment: @Nemi - This post shows you how the connection string should be declared in the app/web config file. See [Store Connection String in Web.config](https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/) for more information. -- "It is a good practice to store the connection string for your application in a config file rather than as a hard coded string in your code."

Comment: @Corak correction, it is `app.config` and not `web.config`. Kindly see post tags and post content before suggesting links that may relatively help OP but may also confuse them.

Comment: @P.Pat - Yes, the link only talks about `web.config`, but for connection strings there is no difference between how they are declared in `web.config` or `app.config`. I tried to make that point with "app/web config", but will be more direct next time.

Comment: See also: [Adding and reading from a Config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864755/adding-and-reading-from-a-config-file) and [What is App.config in C#.NET? How to use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043530/what-is-app-config-in-c-net-how-to-use-it) for further information.

Comment: @Nemi : On the page where u want to use this connection string write this code: `String Conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use the testing / local database that gets installed with VS you're looking for `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb`

So the connection string would be then:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Initial Catalog=Library;Integrated Security=True
```

You can store it in the `app.config` like the other answer, otherwise it might depend on what you're using.

`Initial Catalog` is talking about the name of the database that will be created/used
`Integrated Security` means it will authenticate to the database with the current windows user

You need both of those things in order to connect to the built-in localdb.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for all the responses but I have found my answer in @Corak s answer, the website which is in the comment. however this is the right form of the code that I should used for my string connection:

```
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\Library.mdf; Integrated Security=True";
```

In my case the   `|DataDirectory|`  is the path in my computer for the Database(Library.mdf) so if anyone used this code instead of  `|DataDirectory|` write the path Like the example because if you use `|DataDirectory|` The code will run but nothing in database will happen (or at least for me it didn't work). Here is the example:

```
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=AttachDbFileName=C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyDatabasProject\MyDatabasProject\Library.mdf; Integrated Security=True";
```

My sqlserver is VS2012 local database server v11.0 and that was the thing I had to write in my code specifically.

Hope it's useful