# Reading from a app.config file

Tags: c#, app-config

I am trying to print to `Console.Write` the value of the key `name` from the following `app.config` file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="name" value="Chan" />
      </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

C# code :

```
Console.Write(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"]);
```

Nothing gets printed in the console. Why is this ?

Note: I have added a reference to the `System.Configuration` dll

Comment: could you paste the content of your app.config? also, the app.config is located in the assembly which is being compiled?

Comment: Sorry, i thought i had included it before.

Comment: could you check it's being copied in the bin directory, but with the name changed to <assembly_name>.config (i.e. MyProject.Exe.Config)?

Comment: Try doing `Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Length); Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys));` to see if the key actually exists there. There might be a different problem.

Comment: The length is `0` (zero) what does this mean ?

Comment: I removed the `app.comfig` file and recreated it. and now i get `1` for all`Allkeys.Length`. But when the line `Console.Write(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"]);` gets executed i see the `key` printed to the console (`name`) and not the `value` of the key which is `chan`. Why is this ?

Comment: Probably because the value of the key "name" is actually "name" and not "chan.

Comment: Yorye Nathan -Then it would display "name" it would not be blank

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718698/i-cant-write-into-config-file/10718733#10718733

Answer (score 4, accepted):

below code gives you the content of active config file.

```
var content  = File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
```

Check what you get as `content`, is it contain  `key="name" value="Chan"` or something else 
?

if you given  `<add key="name" value="Chan" />` then 
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"] should return as `Chan`

Answer (score -1):

Given that your XML file (app.config) is **properly formatted**, try below.
Declare a variable and assign the variable the AppSettings value. Similar like-

```
string sName = "";
sName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"].ToString();
```

Comment: Not sure why getting these negative voting but the above does work for me. Hope someone explain me my fault. Thanks.

Comment: Copying the value to a string will not help in anyway. Your answer is wrong, that is why you are getting the downvotes.

Comment: I think the user can figure out what I am trying to say. I just provided a way to check (during debug) if the value is actually being read. If the XML file is properly formatted, I do not understand why the above will NOT work.

Comment: Illep already try that, he print value of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"])` using  `Console.Write`