# Is there any way to access the value of custom config section using the key as in AppSettings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, custom-configuration

I have a customized config section in my web.config like this:

```
     <configSection>
            <section name="CustomConfig" type="ConfigSectionRoot" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
        </configSection>


    <CustomConfig>
    <ConfigRoot>
        <add key="DataBase" value="CouchDB"/>
        <add key="FrontEnd" value="Asp.Net"/>
        <add key="AppName" value="Virtual WorkPlace"/>
      </ConfigRoot>
    </CustomConfig>

<AppSettings>
<add key="DataBase" value="CouchDB"/>
</AppSettings>
```

My ConfigSectionRoot.cs is like this:

```
public class ConfigSectionRoot:ConfigurationSection
    {

        [ConfigurationProperty("key", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public string Key
        {
            get
            {
                return ((string)(base["key"]));
            }
            set
            {
                base["key"] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("value", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = false, IsRequired = false)]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return ((string)(base["value"]));
            }
            set
            {
                base["value"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

If i use AppSettings Instead of Custom Config I could access it like:

```
string results= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"];
// results wil contain "CouchDB"
```

Is there any way to achieve the same thing in Customized Config section ??? Pls help me out

Comment: You should derive from ConfigurationSection, not ConfigurationElement. Take a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10718830/205859).

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları
I have changed and i can access it. But my question is can i access the value using the key as in AppSettings

Comment: I don't think so. ConfigurationManager.AppSetting propbably checks elements inside <appSettings></appSettings>

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları
Fine.. Is there anything similar to that..can we use something like CustomConfig.ConfigRoot["Database"] to get the value..

Comment: You can implement an indexer in your ConfigSectionRoot class.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları
Can u explain me with a sample code for that..

Comment: Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3935331/205859) is also helpful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### NameValueSectionHandler

If your configuration doesn't need to be more than a key-value store, I'd go for a [NameValueSectionHandler](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/shyjumohan/creating-custom-sections-and-encryption-in-web-config/).

```
<section name="customConfig" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
<!-- ... -->
<customConfig>
  <add key="DataBase" value="CouchDB" />
  <add key="FrontEnd" value="Asp.Net" />
  <add key="AppName" value="Virtual WorkPlace" />
</customConfig>
```

You can then read it out, just like the appSettings:

```
var customConfig = (System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customConfig");//i have changed like this and it worked fine
var database = customConfig["DataBase"];
```

#### SingleTagSectionHandler

You could also achieve the same with a SingleTagSection:

```
<section name="customConfig" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler"/>
<!-- ... -->
<customConfig database="CouchDB" frontEnd="Asp.Net" appName="Virtual Workplace" />
```

And then query it with:

```
var customConfig = (System.Collections.Hashtable) System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetConfig("customConfig");
var database = customConfig["database"];
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help.. i didn get the expected result wen tried ur code.. I hav jus made a slight alteration then it worked.. Please review it..

Comment: I'm sorry, it was copy-paste work from what I knew and what I could quickly find online. Didn't test it through, but you solved it just right, tnx ;)

Answer (score 0):

The .NET configuration framework provides the [ConfigurationElementCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx) class for representing lists of elements. In the above example, your implementation of the ConfigurationElementCollection is represented by the *ConfigRoot* xml element. The collection should have child elements of type "ConfigSectionRoot". The ConfigSectionRoot class should inherit from ConfigurationElement, not Configuration Section.

You must create a separate class representing the CustomConfig xml element. This class is the root of you configuration and must inherit from ConfigurationSection.

```
public class CustomConfigConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    public static CustomConfigConfigurationSection Section
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customConfig") as CustomConfigConfigurationSection;
        }
    }

    public ConfigConfigurationElementCollection ConfigRoot
    {
        get
        {
            return this["configRoot"] as ConfigConfigurationElementCollection;
        }
    }
}

public class ConfigConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("key")]
    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["key"];
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("value")]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["value"];
        }
    }
}

public class ConfigConfigurationElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new ConfigConfigurationElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((ConfigConfigurationElement)element).Key;
    }

    // Slight hack to look up the direct value property of the ConfigConfigurationElement from the collection indexer
    public new string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return (base[key] as ConfigConfigurationElement).Value;//I m getting the error in this line
        }
    }
}
```

Direct usage:

```
var section = CustomConfigConfigurationSection.Section;
var value = section.ConfigRoot["key"];
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help.. I hav tried as u specified.. But im getting a "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Where du you get this exception?

Comment: return (base[key] as ConfigConfigurationElement).Value;